# Python 3: Is there a way to get the line number of an error and the error statement when using exec

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to get the line number of the error through executing a file? Let's say that I have the following code:

```
exec(open("test.py").read())
```

And the file has an error, in which IDLE pops up the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\henrydavidzhu\Desktop\Arshi\arshi.py", line 349, in runFile
    exec(open(self.fileName).read())
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I want to know the error statement (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`), and the line number. This is not a duplicate because I am using `Python 3`, and not `Python 2`.

Comment: You mean you want to know the line number programmatically?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly.

Comment: Side question: why are you not using `import`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You have some **python** code and you're using `exec` to execute it, why not use `import` instead?

Comment: why not launch a subprocess? then you can capture what ever you want

Comment: @Arshia: nothing changed in that respect between Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    exec(open('test.py').read())
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, ex, tb = sys.exc_info()
    imported_tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1]
    line_number = imported_tb_info[1]
    print_format = '{}: Exception in line: {}, message: {}'
    print(print_format.format(exc_type.__name__, line_number, ex))
```